# Switching the values of two fields/columns in SQL Server without third variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

As a result of a mistake during an import to the a test table called CUSTOMERS, I found myself needing to switch the values of two columns in SQL Server.

I mistakenly imported the respective values for LASTNAME and FIRSTNAME into the opposite fields (i.e. the customer last name was imported into first name, and vice versa).  To remedy this, I ran the following query in SQL Server 2008 R2, of course not expecting it to work:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET LASTNAME=FIRSTNAME, FIRSTNAME=LASTNAME
```

Surprisingly, it worked!  The limited programming experience I've had (high school, a few college courses) always followed the paradigm that switching two values required the presence of a third variable to "hold" the value of one of the initial values.  In other words, I expected to have to run the following query:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET SOMEOTHERFIELD = LASTNAME
SET LASTNAME = FIRSTNAME
SET FIRSTNAME = SOMEOTHERFIELD
```

Is this behavior only seen in SQL Server 2008 R2, or does this represent some other underlying facet of relational theory that I'm missing?

Comment: If it has to have the smarts to roll back the transaction it makes sense that it would work that way.

Comment: That SQL statement is valid in most every RDBMS. It's standard SQL. Think of it like that: you have an OLD row and a NEW row. All references to columns point to the OLD row. When all is done, OLD is replaced by NEW.

Comment: It's vendor specific; in *MySQL* 5 you would end up with both columns containing LASTNAME ("Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right")

Comment: I think I would have changed the column names in the table definition instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because the way a update works:

In the set clause are construct a pseudo-table. The rows in this table are build by copying values from the columns that are not mentioned from the original row to a new row. The columns are assigned all at once. That is, the unit of work is a row, not one column at a time. The last step is to delete the olds rows and insert the new rows. Internally, a update is select, delete, insert.

Comment: By the way, its why you are not supposed to use tables with too many columns (if the table are updated constantly).

Comment: In SQL Server updates will generally be carried out in place unless you are updating the clustered index key and the row needs to move.

Answer (score 4):

This is for the same reason that you can't define a column alias in a `SELECT` list then reference the alias elsewhere in the same `SELECT` list. [To quote Joe Celko](http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.com/2006/06/reference-alias-field-name.html)

> Things happen "all at once" in SQL, not "from left to right" as they
>   would in a sequential file/procedural language model

Expressions that appear in the same logical query processing phase are evaluated as if at the same point in time. For more about all–at–once operations see [this link.](http://www.ndc2010.no/index.aspx?id=268800)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the source values are prepared first (and thus stored in an internal third holder) and applied afterward.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Update statements are expected to simultaneously update the columns specified in the UPDATE Statement in most DBMS. It's great to learn things by experience :)